# How to compare nullable int with list<int>?

Tags: c#

`var selectId = array.Where(x => x.Id != null);`

`selectId.Where(x => x.Id == settings.PersonIds);`

**Id** is a nullable int and **settings.PersonIds** is a list of int.

How do i compare and check if the id is the same as settings.PersonIds?

Edit* i am trying to see if the list of int (settings.PersonIds) contains the int (Id)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - that's much clearer than just *describing* your variables. But how would you *expect* to compare a single nullable int with a list of integers? A list isn't a single value.

Comment: Just to be sure I understood you correctly, are you trying to compare an **int** (Id) and a **list of int** (settings.PersonIds), or are you trying to see if the **list of int** (settings.PersonIds) contains the **int** (Id)

Comment: Sorry yeah im trying to see if the list of int (settings.PersonIds) contains the int (Id)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=net-6.0)

```
array.Where(x => x.Id.HasValue && settings.PersonIds.Contains(x.Id.Value));
```